# Diffrence view count between standard experience and classical experience

Tags: sharepoint-online

One of my user asks me a question about the file view counter in Sharepoint,
He wants to know that it is the difference between the view counter of the classical experience and that of the standard experience,
On the same file we have a difference between the two experiences:
[image: Classical experience]

[image: Standard experience]

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce your issue. It’s the default behavior.

When we view the document in modern view, the views counter in modern view plus 1 but the classic view not. When we view the document in classic view, the classic view counter plus 1.

Comment: Thanks, So they are not linked ? 
If i view the document in classic view, counter only +1 on classic counter ?